# How do you render OpenGL-ES to an external screen using the VGA out adapter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, opengl-es

I've been developing a 3D program for the iPad and iPhone and would like to be able to render it to an external screen. According to my understanding, you have to do something similar to the below code to implement it, (found at: [Sunsetlakesoftware.com](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/ipad.html)):

```
if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1)
{
    // External screen attached
}
else
{
    // Only local screen present
}

CGRect externalBounds = [externalScreen bounds];
externalWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:externalBounds];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]  initWithFrame:externalBounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[externalWindow addSubview:backgroundView];

[backgroundView release];

externalWindow.screen = externalScreen;
[externalWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

However, I'm not sure what to change to do this to an OpenGL project. Does anyone know what you would do to implement this into the defualt openGL project for iPad or iPhone in XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to get ANY OpenGL-ES content to render onto an external display. It's actually really straightforward. You just copy your renderbuffer to a UIImage then display that UIImage on the external screen view. The code to take a snapshot of your renderbuffer is below:

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{
// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// Create a CGImage with the pixel data
// If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
// otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

// OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
// Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
    // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
    CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
    widthInPoints = width / scale;
    heightInPoints = height / scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
}
else {
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    widthInPoints = width;
    heightInPoints = height;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
}

CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
// Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
// The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

// Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Clean up
free(data);
CFRelease(ref);
CFRelease(colorspace);
CGImageRelease(iref);

return image;
}
```

Although, for some reason I've never been able to get glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES to return the proper backingwidth and backingheight, so I've had to use my own function to calculate those. Just pop this into your rendering implementation and place the result onto the external screen using a timer. If anyone can make any improvements to this method, please let me know.

Comment: If you were simply looking to mirror rendered content to the external display, a more performant approach might be to use `glReadPixels()` to get the current rendered scene, and then update a texture that is rendered onto a quad in the OpenGL ES layer on your external display.  This would avoid the costly Core Graphics image redraw and updating of the UIImageView.  I do something like that in this OpenGL ES 2.0 sample application: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll try that out and see if it works. I didn't realize that CoreGraphics was so slow to update. I thought it was just because I had a semi-large model (100k faces). It would be nice to get more than 3-4 fps on the external screen!

Comment: By the way, what does the sample ColorTracking.zip application do? I don't have an iPhone to test it on, and it doesn't seem to do anything on the iPad.

Comment: I explain it here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios , but it performs realtime color-based object tracking using the iPhone's camera.  Yes, it's hard to use without a camera attached, but you can extract the pixel reading and texture mapping parts (although you'll need to convert them from the OpenGL ES 2.0 shader-based approach I use here).

Comment: I need to convert a 3D rendering to a UIImage, and this appears to work, unless I'm using multi-sampling.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do to render OpenGL ES content on the external display is to either create a UIView that is backed by a CAEAGLLayer and add it as a subview of the `backgroundView` above, or take such a view and move it to be a subview of `backgroundView`.

In fact, you can remove the `backgroundView` if you want and just place your OpenGL-hosting view directly on the `externalWindow` UIWindow instance.  That window is attached to the UIScreen instance that represents the external display, so anything placed on it will show on that display.  This includes OpenGL ES content.

There does appear to be an issue with particular types of OpenGL ES content, as you can see in the experimental support I've tried to add to my [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) application.  If you look in the source code there, I attempt to migrate my rendering view to an external display, but it never appears.  I have done the same with other OpenGL ES applications and had their content render fine, so I believe there might be an issue with the depth buffer on the external display.  I'm still working to track that down.

Comment: Let me know if my solution helps you to get your molecules code displaying properly. It's not quite as fast as just rendering twice might be for light geometry, but for heavy geometry, which is what I'm dealing with, it's probably faster since it doesn't depend on how many polygons you are rendering. Some models I'm displaying have over 800,000 triangles. Granted my framerate with those is only about 2fps.

Comment: @Davido - In my benchmarks, this would be a very slow way to display this content to an external screen.  `glReadPixels()` is a slow operation, but not as slow as drawing an image to a Core Graphics context and then updating a corresponding UIImageView.  For a 1024x768 display, I doubt that you could achieve a 30-60 FPS refresh rate this way. It's an interesting idea, but impractical in this case.